# Smart find a vertices

Tags: scripting

Hi and thanks in advance.
I am trying to find a reference point on a 3d scanned arm model in Blender, so I can know its current position and rotation. A phyton script to find a certain vertices, let's say the one on middle finger's tip, would help me a lot. Can someone lead me in the right direction, please? (With no opencv involvement)

Comment: What have you got so far, could you show us a part of your script? What do you mean exactly by "*find a certain vertices*"? Which ones, how? By name? How would a script know what is a middle finger? How would Blender know which vertex from said finger you want? Could you clarify exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: You have asked how would Blender know what is middle finger? That is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score -2):

I see that it is not something you can do in blender. I will have to use OpenCV feature recognition for such a purpose. Thanks for responses.

Comment: Please don't add answers to comment... if you found that's impossible in blender, please describe why, otherwise nobody knows what you discovered...